# Audio books image building fails on Windows Server 2019 Core (Hypervizor and VM)

Tags: hyper-v, ntfs, refs

We are migrating from a 2008R2 server to 2019 core standard with Hyper-v role. 2019 Server VM's with GUI.

We burn audio books with files shared from 2008R2. Now I try do the same, from a Virtualized 2019 server.

The PC's (windows 7) that are handeling the cd's burning process can see the shares just fine, but the burning process does not work. The files are .mp3 files, and some files that create the DAISY structure of the CD. The filenames on the CD (The CD's are in DAISY format) are wrong and do not play on Daisy players. I understand that the burning process is our responsibility.

But the process runs fine when the data resides on a c:\ drive.

- Data shared residing on the c:\ drive of the hypervizor =The process runs fine (premastering of the image to burn)
- Data shared residing on another volume of the hypervizor = We get an error in a log file of the CD burning software "Overflowed directory" or something

-Data shared residing on a volume of the VM (.vhdx file) = an error

-Data shared residing on the C:\ drive of the VM = all is fine.

All volumes are NTFS formatted, so are the clients. We also have XP machine's and they run fine after I activated SMB 1 on the servers. But I believe they copy the data to an external FAT32 drive and do the processing from there.

What is even stranger, If I format the VM volumes to FAT32 the process works, but the premastering is extremely slow. ( Very slow on IDE, half as slow on SCSI, on a gen1 VM). When going back to NTFS or ReFS, the shares are fine, but the burning goes wrong.

I'm not asking for a solution for the CD burning process.

But might there be a difference from sharing files from a SMB share on a c:\ drive then from another drive. Or could this be OS' related? The permissions between al drives seem to be the same. I also think about ISO levels. I'm not an IT pro, but need to get this fixed.

So conclusion, all is fine from sharing files on c:\ drive's, virtualized or not. Any other drive's do not work. The file sharing is always fine, but the burning process is not.

Mounting an NTFS volume (a VHDX file) to a folder on c:\ does not work in the virtual machine.

Thank you for reading this vague issue.

Kind regards,

Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this one out. The CD burning software is quite old and runs on win 7. I could burn CD's from data on c:\ drive. System drives have a setting 8.3 filenames enabled by default. Other volumes don't. So I enabled this setting on other volumes and Voila. CD's are correctly burnt.

However, from within a VM the process is horribly slow. I will tinker with the virtual switch settings, etc. Copying to a 2008R2 from within a VM (robocopy) is tremendously slow. From the VM to the host is very fast, maybe because the OS is allowed to use the NIC of the VM.

Should somebody have some tips in tweaking a virtual switch, bearing in mind we have some old hardware and software.

I'll try and a copy from the host OS to the 2008R2, then I can determine of the "issue" is to be found in the virtual switch.

Some links concerning the 8.3 filenames :

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/778273-windows-2012-r2-file-migration-long-path-names-fix

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/121007/how-to-disable-8-3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff621566(v=ws.11)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff621566(v=ws.11)

Kind regards,

Hendrik